# Inner and outer regularity of measures in terms of a continuity condition

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space. On the power set $\mathcal{P}(X)$ one can define a topology as follows. For two subsets $K, G \subseteq X$ consider the interval $[K, G] := \{ A \subseteq X \mid K \subseteq A \subseteq G \}$. If $K$ is compact and $G$ is open then let us refer to $[K, G]$ as a compact-open interval. Then the collection of all compact-open intervals forms a base for a topology on $\mathcal{P}(X)$. A set $\mathcal{R} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ is dense if $[K, G] \cap \mathcal{R} \neq \emptyset$ for all compact-open intervals $[K, G]$, i.e. there is $A \in \mathcal{R}$ with $K \subseteq A \subseteq G$. In particular, the set of all compact subsets and the set of all open sets is dense in $\mathcal{P}(X)$.

All of this and the following can be found in [Dinculeanu, "Vector Measures", Section III.§15].

Let $\mathcal{R} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ be an arbitrary nonempty set and $\mu : \mathcal{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ an arbitrary set function. A set $A \in \mathcal{R}$ is said to be

- regular w.r.t. $\mu$ $\quad :\Leftrightarrow \quad$ $\mu$ is continuous in $A$, i.e. for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a compact-open interval $[K, G]$ with $A \in [K, G]$ such that for all $A' \in [K, G] \cap \mathcal{R}$ it holds $|\mu(A) - \mu(A')| < \varepsilon$.
- inner regular w.r.t. $\mu$ $\quad :\Leftrightarrow \quad$ $\mu$ is left continuous in $A$ meaning that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a compact-open interval $[K, X]$ with $A \in [K, X]$ such that for all $A' \in [K, A] \cap \mathcal{R}$ it holds $|\mu(A) - \mu(A')| < \varepsilon$
- outer regular w.r.t. $\mu$ $\quad :\Leftrightarrow \quad$ $\mu$ is right continuous in $A$ meaning that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a compact-open interval $[\emptyset, G]$ with $A \in [\emptyset, G]$ such that for all $A' \in [A, G] \cap \mathcal{R}$ it holds $|\mu(A) - \mu(A')| < \varepsilon$

The set function $\mu$ is called

- (inner / outer) regular on $\mathcal{R}' \subseteq \mathcal{R}$ whenever all $A \in \mathcal{R}'$ are (inner / outer) regular w.r.t. $\mu$ and
- (inner / outer) regular if $\mu$ is (inner / outer) regular on $\mathcal{R}$.

Facts:

1. If $\mathcal{R}$ is a ring then $\mu$ is regular $\Leftrightarrow$ $\mu$ is inner regular and outer regular.
2. If $\mathcal{R}$ is a ring and $\mathcal{R}$ is dense in $\mathcal{P}(X)$ then $\mu$ is regular $\Leftrightarrow$ $\mu$ is inner regular $\Leftrightarrow$ $\mu$ is outer regular. In particular, this is true for the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{R} = \mathcal{B}(X)$.
3. If $\mathcal{R} = \mathcal{B}(X)$, $\mu : \mathcal{B}(X) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a finite signed Borel measure and $\mathcal{R}' \subseteq \mathcal{B}(X)$ then

   - $\mu$ is inner regular on $\mathcal{R}'$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $|\mu|(A) = \sup \{ |\mu|(K) \mid A \supseteq K \textrm{ compact} \}$ for all $A \in \mathcal{R}'$ and
   - $\mu$ is outer regular on $\mathcal{R}'$
     $\Leftrightarrow$ $|\mu|(A) = \inf \{ |\mu|(K) \mid A \subseteq G \textrm{ open} \}$ for all $A \in \mathcal{R}'$

The latter two sup/inf properties are usually what is referred to as inner and outer regularity of a measure. So, we see that (inner and outer) regularity can be described by continuity properties of the set function $\mu$.

Questions:

1. Does the above topology on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ has a name?
2. Is it possible to extend the above setup to

   - general Hausdorff spaces $X$,
   - potentially infinite positive measures $\mu : \mathcal{B}(X) \to [0, \infty]$ or infinite signed measures $\mu : \mathcal{B}(X) \to [-\infty, \infty]$ and
   - and characterize inner regularity w.r.t. other sets such as closed sets or zero sets (or outer regularity w.r.t. cozero sets) of such measures by similar continuity properties w.r.t. a suitable topology on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ (or just on $\mathcal{B}(X)$)?

Comment: I'm also interested in this topology. Did anything ever come of this question?